# Classical Lie group quotient-ed by its maximal parabolic subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form, orthogonal-matrices

Let $B$ is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ then the corresponding complex orthogonal group is $\{g : GL(n, \mathbb{C}): B(gx, gy) =(x,y) \}$

In particular we use $$B (x,y) = \sum\limits_{1\leq l \leq m}x^ly^l - \sum\limits_{m \leq l \leq n}x^ly^l, \; n=2m \; \text{or}\; 2m+1,$$ and denote $$O(n, \mathbb{C}) = \{g : GL(n, \mathbb{C}): B(gx, gy) =(x,y) \}.$$

A linear subspace $E \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is totally isotropic if $B(E,E) =0.$ The parabolic subgroups of $O(n, \mathbb{C})$ are the $$P_{E_1, \cdots, E_k} = \{ g \in O(n,\mathbb{C}): gE_l =E_l \; \text{for}\; 1 \leq l \leq k\}$$

where $0 \neq E_1 \subset \cdots \subset E_k$ is a sequence of totally isotropic subspaces.

Now the maximal parabolic subgroups of $O(n, \mathbb{C})$ are the $$P_E = \{ g \in O(n, \mathbb{C}) : gE=E\},$$ where $E$ is nonzero totally isotropic in $\mathbb{C}^n.$

We know that $O(n, \mathbb{C})/P_E$ is a projective variety. In particular, that should be a flag variety.

My question is:1) What should be the exact presentation of the variety $O(n, \mathbb{C})/P_E?$

2) Can we do the similar thing for $O(n, \mathbb{R})$ or $SO(n, \mathbb{R})?$

Any help we be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If $m\leq n/2$ is the dimension of $E$, the $O(n,\mathbb C)/P_E$ is the variety of all $m$-dimensional isotropic subspaces of $\mathbb C^n$. (It is easy to see that $O(n,\mathbb C)$ acts transitively on the set of such subspaces and $P_E$ is the stabilizer of one of them.)

2) This depends on what you mean by "the similar thing". On the one hand, $O(n,\mathbb R)$ and $SO(n,\mathbb R)$act transitively on the space of all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus, you can view the Grassmannian $Gr(k,\mathbb R^n)$ as a homogeneous space of $O(n,\mathbb R)$ and $SO(n,\mathbb R)$. This leads to the well known presentation $ Gr(k,\mathbb R^n)=O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ and similar for $SO$.

However, $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ do not have parabolic subgroups since they are compact. If you want a real analog of those (and something that is closer to the complex case), you have to go to the indefinite orthogonal groups $O(p,q)$ for $p+q=n$. For those you have isotropic subspaces of dimensions $1\leq k\leq min(p,q)$ and the stabilizer of such an isotropic subspace is a parabolic subgroup $P_k\subset O(p,q)$. The generalized flag variety $O(p,q)/P_k$ then is the variety of $k$-dimensional isotropic subspaces of $\mathbb R^{p+q}$. The closest analogy to the complex case is obtained for the spilt real forms $O(m,m)$ and $O(m,m+1)$.

**Edit** (in view of your comment): What you write there about the complex case is not quite correct. In the definition of $W_m$ you have to add the condition that $B(v_1,v_j)=0$ for all $i$ and $j$ to make sure that the span of your vectors is totally isotropic. Moreover, the group $O(m,\mathbb C)$ should not be used here. The parabolic subgroup $P_E$ has a natural quotient (known as the Levi-factor) isomorphic to $GL(m,\mathbb C)\times O(n-2m,\mathbb C)$, and the bundle $W_m$ is associated to the standard representation of $GL(m,\mathbb C)$, so it is just a $GL(m,\mathbb C)$ vector bundle.

In the real cases and for a definite bilinear form, the situation is easier. There you have $Gr(k,\mathbb R^n)\cong O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ and the analog of $W_m$ now really is formed by $k$-tuples of linearly independent vectos and this is an $O(k)$ bundle (so it carries a natural bundle metric). For $SO$ and $SU$ the situation is very similar.

Comment: Define $W_m(\mathbb{C}^n) = \{(v_1, \cdots, v_m): v_i's  \; \text{are linearly independent vectors in} \; \mathbb{C}^n  \}.$ Then the map $W_m(\mathbb{C}^n)  \to O(n, \mathbb{C})/P_E $  given by span is an $O(m, \mathbb{C})$-bundle.



Then what should be the analogous $W_m$ in the cases $O(n, \mathbb{R})$, $SO(n, \mathbb{R}), SU(n)?$

Comment: I have edited my answer to address this.

Comment: Let $X= \{ \text{all m-dimensional isotropic subspaces of} \; \mathbb{C}^n \}. $ I want to construct a $SO$-bundle over $X$. Is it possible to construct such bundle via inputting some extra conditions in my $W_m(\mathbb{C}^n) = \{ (v_1, \cdots, v_m) : v_i's \text{are linearly independent in} \; \mathbb{C}^n , B(v_i, v_j) =0 \; \text{for all}\; i, j \}$.

Comment: I don't think that the group $SO(m,\mathbb C)$ is nicely related to the quotient $SO(n,\mathbb C)/P_m$. The latter deals with isotropic subspaces that do not carry a natural bilinear form. Of course, you can look at the variety of non-degenerate subspaces of dimension $m$ (which is isomorphic to $O(n,\mathbb C)/(O(m,\mathbb C)\times O(n-m,\mathbb C)$ and carries a natural $O(m,\mathbb C)$-bundle, but this is not a generalized flag variety in the usual sense.

Comment: I hope that one can have a similar bundle for $Sp(n, \mathbb{C})$ for the antisymmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ given by $B(x,y) = \sum\limits_{1 \leq l \leq n}(x^ly^{n+l} - x^{n+l}y^l).$ Therefore we get a $Sp(m, \mathbb{C})$-bundle with total space $W_m= \{ (v_1, \cdots, v_m): v_i  \text{'s are linearly independent vectors in and} \; B(v_i, v_j) =0 \text{for all} \; i , j \}$. If I put an additional condition $<v_i, v_j> = \delta_{ij}$ in $W_m,$ then I think the fibre is $Sp(n , \mathbb{C}) \cap U(2n) = Sp(n).$

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming at. The bundle $W_m$ does not have a natural skew form, since there is not induced form on an isotropic subspace. The natural group acting there is again $GL(m,\mathbb C)$ (which is a quotient of the parabolic subgroup of $Sp(n,\mathbb C)$ that underlies this example). You can always break the available symmetry by artificially introducing some structure, but then you have to be careful whether span is still surjective when restricted to the subspace you consider.

Comment: Actually, I want to view the classifying space of the classical Lie groups as isotropic flag manifolds with respect to some appropriate bilinear forms. That is why I want to construct such bundles and prove that $W_m(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is contractible when $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Now I understand your motivation, but I don't that this is the right way to construct the classifying spaces. I would try to use the variety of those subspaces for which the restriction of the bilinear form is non-degnerate. These also are homomgeneous spaces, in the orthogonal case, you simply get $O(n,\mathbb C)/(O(m,\mathbb C)\times O(n-m,\mathbb C)$. Then you can take orthonormal bases (or their symplectic analogs) to define $W_m$, which naturally is a principal fiber bundle with structure group $O(m,\mathbb C)$. Things can be done similarly in the symplectic case.

Comment: Yeah. You are correct. But I have another question regarding your suggestion. We know the construction of Schubert cell complex structure for the case: all V,  k- dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$. But if there is bilinear form B on $\mathbb{C}^n$.How to calculate the Schubert cell structure of the set of all V,  k- dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n such that B restricted on V is non singular.